# Black screen after screensaver blanking

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, 17.04

When trying to wake up my monitors after being switched off via the xscreensaver, I get a black screen. The monitors do not wake up. If I manually turn on the monitors, the monitors report no input (and go back to power saving mode).

- Ubuntu 17.04
- Nvidia GTX 1060
- nvidia-381.22
- Two HP Z27s monitors driven via DisplayPort cables

I can switch to a separate console (alt-ctrl-F2) and both monitors wake up and display normally.

After switching back to F7, the video card continues to output a black screen on the graphics console.

If I restart lightdm via a text console, then the graphics come alive (but of course, I'm logged out).

Any help would be most appreciated. (It is disappointing that the nvidia card is causing me so much trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Ubuntu 46.04. I think is a bug with this Kernel (4.10.0-27-generic)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1705884

Answer (score 0):

Install and enable the [Caffeine GNOME extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/).
It will disable your screensaver.